# Active Directory expired certs causing issues with 802.1x authentication

Tags: active-directory, certificate, 802.1, expired

We are in the process of rolling out 802.1x in our environment.  With that said, there are quite a few clients that revert back to an older (expired) certificate which prevents them from authenticating and getting network access. Can the expired cert/s be removed from AD or will this cause an issue with the CRL? Management would like to move forward with this project but this authentication issue is a deal breaker...

Thanks ahead

Bill

Comment: Are these Windows 7 clients?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2494172